# KabelExtra background color for specific row column or subset of table

Tags: r, html-table, kableextra

Im trying to make a html Table with KableExtra. I need to colour a subset of the table using a condition or by row and column number. I already have cell_spec set and that works nicely. But when I try to color I have an issue. May be Im just too dumb.

I have given what I get and what is desired here.

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POEkL.jpg)

[This is the desirable output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RErTl.png)

I have tried the following but I could only achieve one part, but not both.

```
beauty <- report %>%
  mutate (
    `c.Chg  OI` = ifelse ( `c.Chg  OI` <0 , cell_spec(`c.Chg  OI`, "html", color = "red"), 
                                                        cell_spec(`c.Chg  OI`, "html", color = "green")),

    `c.Net Chg` = ifelse ( `c.Net Chg` <0 , cell_spec(`c.Net Chg`, "html", color = "red"),
                                                    cell_spec(`c.Net Chg`, "html", color = "green")),

    `p. Chg  OI` = ifelse ( `p. Chg  OI` <0 , cell_spec(`p. Chg  OI`, "html", color = "red"), 
                                                        cell_spec(`p. Chg  OI`, "html", color = "green")),

    `p. Net Chg` = ifelse ( `p. Net Chg` <0 , cell_spec(`p. Net Chg`, "html", color = "red"),
                                                    cell_spec(`p. Net Chg`, "html", color = "green")),

    `c.Trend` = ifelse ( `c.Trend` == "BULLISH", cell_spec(`c.Trend`, color = "white", background ="green"),   
                            cell_spec(`c.Trend`, color = "white", background ="red") ), 

    `p. Trend` = ifelse ( `p. Trend` == "BULLISH", cell_spec(`p. Trend`, color = "white", background ="green"),   
                            cell_spec(`p. Trend`, color = "white", background ="red") ), 

    `c.status` = ifelse ( `c.status` == "Long Buildup" | `c.status` == "Short Covering" , 
                             cell_spec(`c.status`, color = "white", background ="green"),   
                             cell_spec(`c.status`, color = "white", background ="red") ), 

    `p. status` = ifelse ( `p. status` == "Long Buildup" | `p. status` == "Short Covering" , 
                             cell_spec(`p. status`, color = "white", background ="green"),   
                             cell_spec(`p. status`, color = "white", background ="red") )
  ) 


  colnames(beauty) <- c( "Trend" , "status", "OI", "Chg  OI", "LTP", "Net Chg", "Strike Price", 
                                           "Net Chg" , "LTP" , "Chg  OI", "OI" , "status", "Trend"    )
  itm_row <- dim(filter(report, `Strike Price` < cmp))[1]


beauty %>% 
  kable("html", escape = F,align = "c" ) %>%
  column_spec(7, bold = T) %>%
  add_header_above(c( "CALL" = 6, "", "PUT" = 6)) %>%
  add_header_above ( header= caption, font_size=16, bold = T  ) %>%
  column_spec(1:6, color = "grey", background = "#F5F5F5")%>%
  row_spec(3:nrow(beauty), bold = F, color = "grey", background = "white") %>%
  row_spec(3:nrow(beauty), bold = F, color = "grey", background = "white")%>%
  column_spec(8:13, color = "grey", background = "#F5F5F5") %>%
  row_spec(1:itm_row, bold = F, color = "grey", background = "white")%>%
  kable_styling("bordered",full_width = F, font_size = 12, position = "center" )
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean by you have cell_spec set, because that's where you would define a conditional background color using the background argument, before passing the data frame to kable. Can we see your cell_spec call?

Comment: Hi, I have added my cell_spac calls also.. if you could view the output from the line above you can get an idea what I mean. Thanks for your time and Im happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, according to the package documentation, kableExtra does not currently support coloring the background of an entire cell. It would need to insert background color CSS at the `<td>` level, but cell_spec only inserts in the `<span>` level.

Some background on the issue here:

https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/327

There is, however, a workaround, if you are able to work with HTML coding yourself. Using the kable_as_xml command, you can go in and alter the classes of the cells you would like to have a different background color, and define said background color in the CSS. It would require some doing, but demonstration of how to go about this is here:

https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/kableExtra_and_xml2.html